# Change font size in tables document-wide

Tags: tables, fontsize

Using `scrartcl` as my document class, tables are set in a slightly larger font size than my normal text (12pt vs. 11pt I suppose). How can I change the font size for tables document wide? At the moment I just add a `\small` to all my tables.

Comment: Are you sure something else isn't doing this? The KOMA classes don't change the fontsize of tables AFAIK.

Comment: As Alan said, this is not the expected bahaviour with the default settings, can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the change in the font size that you mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}{%
  \if@tablecaptionabove\let\caption\captionabove
  \else\let\caption\captionbelow\fi
  \small\@float{table}%
}{%
  \end@float
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. Is it possible that some of the packages I use, such as `longtable`, `colortable`, or `caption` interfere with that?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. The source was copied from the `scrartcl.cls`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the environment hook provided by `etoolbox`. The following code will change the table contents to `\tiny` (well `\tiny` may be better for the demonstration purpose though no one will really use it).

The hook is plugged at `tabular`. Use `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\tiny}` has no effect. And indeed if it has effect, you won't really want it, since it will chang the caption too. You may want to customize the caption by another package like `caption` or ccaption`, rather than change it here.

Since you won't really use a dozen kinds of tabular environment, so call `\AtBeginEnvironment` for those you use will be enough (for the sake of good typographic practice you should not use more than two type of tables, one for short, one for long).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\tiny}

\begin{document}
  Some text in normal text.
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{A table}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      Some text in  table size
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution by Marco, redefining the `table` environment and inserting `\small` is a good approach. However, it doesn't work yet. Of course it could not be tested, since no example has been given.

The macro `\@floatboxreset` calls `\normalsize`. This can be redefined using `\small` instead or just omitting `\normalsize`. To not affect other floats, also this can be done within the `table` redefinition. I called `\normalsize` at the end of the environment.

So, here's a compilable example which works as desired:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}{%
  \if@tablecaptionabove\let\caption\captionabove
  \else\let\caption\captionbelow\fi
  \renewcommand* {\@floatboxreset}{%
    \reset@font\@setminipage}
  \small\@float{table}%
}{%
  \end@float\normalsize
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Text in 10pt

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{l}
Text in 9pt
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Text in 10pt
\end{document}
```

I returned to this question because I dealt with a very similar topic on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=13680&p=51709#p51709) today.

Comment: You don't have to call `\normalsize` at the end of the environment. It is because `\small` will be local to the group closed by `\end`. Also for the `[!htbp]`, I guess what you really want is `[!h]`.

Comment: @Yan Zhou: I guess so, originally I didn't use `\normalsize`, just edited and added it because `\@floatboxreset` used it. Should not hurt. ;-) And `[!htbp]` or `[!h]` doesn't matter, it's just an example and it did it. I don't like to show `[!h]` because in my opinion just `h` is usually too less.

Answer (score 4):

One more easy way to do what you need is to write

```
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\renewcommand{\tabular}{\footnotesize\oldtabular}
```

If you use another table environment than `tabular` (for instance, `tabularx`), you should replace `\tabular` by `\tabularx` in the command:

```
\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\renewcommand{\tabularx}{\footnotesize\oldtabularx}
```

This will not affect table captions. This answer will work for any document class and any definition of the `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 0):

The approached mentioned here are quite useful. Here is another short way to do that, just redefine the table environment as below:

```
 \makeatletter
 \renewenvironment{table}
     {\@float{table} \small}
     {\end@float}
 \makeatother
```

Comment: Cool, it doesn't work if you use table options though, like `\begin{table}[p]`.