# Set font size of tables globally to 8pt

Tags: tables, pdftex, fontsize

I would like to set it to 8pt for tables globally. How would one go about doing that?

I did see this [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20207/change-font-size-in-tables-document-wide).

The solution provided by [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20209/26232) works very well if you want to set  the font size to small/large, without a specific number.

Any help will be nice to have.

@Darko please find here the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\fontsize{8 pt}{10 pt}{\selectfont}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\noindent\begin{table}[htb!]
    \centering
          \def\arraystretch{0.8}%  1 is the default, change whatever you need
    \caption{sum.}
    \label{tab: sum}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lllc@{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{\#} & \textbf{Scope}  &  \textbf{Activity}   & \textbf{Month} \\
        \midrule
        1 & foo                        & bar                  & M1-M24\vspace{1mm}\\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can check which font command you need based on the default document font size (see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc). So, for standard document classes, if the document font size is `11pt` or `12pt` then you should set the table font size to `\scriptsize` to get `8pt` in tables, and if the document font size is `10pt` then you should use `\footnotesize`.

Comment: for example with `\fontsize{8 pt}{10 pt}\selectfont}`?

Comment: You could try this, which relies on the `etoolbox`  package: `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont}` and  probably similarly for `longtable` if you use it.

Comment: Bernard and Zarko: I did not see any difference in font after using either of them

Comment: @Marijn, that's not a bad idea, but that would never be standardised.. as one would always have to look at the cls file.

Comment: @tandem you're right that the settings may need to be changed for different documents - however I assumed that you (and/or other people reading your question) want this for a particular use case (a single document, or a set of documents with the same class and main font size), instead of wanting `8pt` in tables always for every document you make.

Comment: @Marijn, that's fair enough.  if you can write your comment as an answer, I can tick it.

Comment: @tandem, i doubt that your observation is correct. can you show (in question) how you tested mine and  Bernard suggestion?

Comment: @Zarko I can do that later today and add that to the question.

Comment: @Zarko: added the comment